# PowerShell command prints the value rather than executing

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have written a power shell command to achieve a specific function and I'm new to power shell.
That should perform the action and I'm pretty sure I have entered exact working command.
But when I try to execute the command inside for each loop, it prints the command rather than executing. NWAdminCommand is my command and it gets values from user input.

```
$NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action"

foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
    {

      foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
         {
    $NWAdminCommand;
         }
     } 
    }
```

Comment: You have an extra } (last one) you should remove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `$NWAdminCommand` is equivalent to `Write-Host $NWAdminCommand`. In order to execute a command you can prefix it with & or use iex.

```
 & $NWAdminCommand
 iex $NWAdminCommand
```

You can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338015/in-powershell-how-do-you-execute-an-arbitrary-native-command-from-a-string) or this [Microsoft Technet web page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) that explains all the different ways of executing commands.

This is the correct code (assumming that $spWebApp.Sites and $SPSite.AllWebs are not empty collections)

```
$NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action"
foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
      foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
      {
            & $NWAdminCommand
            #iex $NWAdminCommand
      }
}
```