# Different behavior when running ps1 Powershell script with Invoke-Expression vs Powershell -File

Tags: powershell

This is a new question stemming from a previous post at :

[Run Powershell script from inside other Powershell script with dynamic redirection to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903775/run-powershell-script-from-inside-other-powershell-script-with-dynamic-redirecti)

I am running:

```
$logStreams = "2>&1>"

$command = '"C:\myscript.ps1" $_logStreams "C:\outputlog.txt"'

iex "& $command"
```

I observed that calling my script with `iex "& $ command"` is different than running it using `Powershel -File "C:\myscript.ps1"`.

Myscript.ps1 calls a function Download (with some params) which creates and fills up a file $File1 then a second file $File2 (also it generates a third file from the previous two ones).

Then, in the next line in myscript.ps1 after calling Download(), I call another function Cleanup($File1, $File2) which deletes $File1 and $File2. All this works flawlessly with Powershell -File "C:\myscript.ps1" however when using iex "& $command" as above the Cleanup function complains it cannot bind $File1 and $File2 because they are null !

It is like iex executed the Download and Cleanup functions in parallel (call Download, do not wait for it to complete -> immediately call Cleanup). Is that an expected behavior of iex or am I missing something basic here ?