# Syntax for running executables?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this from the PowerShell 3 ISE:

```
&"C:\inetpub\htpasswd.exe -bc C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\password\passMD5.txt sm88555 sm88999"
```

but get this error:

> is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I think PowerShell stops evaluating this correctly after the first space?

Comment: iex - Invoke-Expression [-Command] <string>  [<CommonParameters>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iex` - `Invoke-Expression` I use when & fails

```
$htPassword = "C:\inetpub\htpasswd.exe"
$htParams = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\password\passMD5.txt sm88555 sm88999"
Invoke-Expression -Command "$htPassword $htParams"
```

[myeval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338015/in-powershell-how-do-you-execute-an-arbitrary-native-command-from-a-string) handles both quite well by joel-b-fant

Answer (score 2):

The call operator doesn't interpret entire commandlines/expressions. That is what `Invoke-Expression` is for. Separate the arguments from the command (and from each other) if you want to use the call operator:

```
& "C:\inetpub\htpasswd.exe" -bc "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xyz\password\passMD5.txt" "sm88555" "sm88999"
```