# Duplicate dynamic parameters when calling executable

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell to call an executable `app.exe`.

I can call `app.exe` with a parameter `myparam` multiple times - so this would be a valid call from within powershell:

```
& app.exe --myparam 1 --myparam 2 --myparam 3
```

However, in my scenario I do not know how many instances of `myparam` I need to pass to `app.exe` until runtime.

If I wanted to dynamically pass parameters with *different* names I am aware that I could use splatting - but this doesn't work for me because I cannot add multiple instances of the key `myparam` to the hash table.

Comment: `iex "& app.exe --myparam 1 --myparam 2 --myparam 3"`.. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338015/how-do-you-execute-an-arbitrary-native-command-from-a-string

Comment: Just what I was after - thank you!