# How to run nswag code generating script on MacOS

Tags: .net-core, nswag

I'm trying to run a code generating script from terminal within vs code on a mac, but each time I get the the following error:

```
cmd: "..\node_modules\.bin\nswag" run
cmd : The term 'cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At ...
```

here's the ps1 script I was trying to run:

```
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
Set-Location $directorypath
$cmdString = """" + "..\node_modules\.bin\nswag" + """" + " run";
Write-Host 'cmd:' $cmdString
cmd /c $cmdString
```

Comment: the problem seems to be caused by no 'cmd' on mac OS, but i installed PowerShell for mac, and still doesn't work.

Comment: i think this would work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338047/876814

Comment: `iex $cmdString`