# Azure Devops - Get All variables with specific prefix dynamically (azure cli)

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, powershell-core

Currently I'm using azure devops to deploy an app container to azure.

I've created my release pipeline and added each ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE manually through the interface.

I wondering if is there any way to get it dynamically, I mean add the environment variables with a given prefix and add to the command.

Currently this is the command that I'm using:

```bash
az containerapp create --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) --name $(ContainerAppName) --container-name $(ContainerAppName) --environment $(CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT) --cpu $(ContainerCpu) --memory $(ContainerMemory) --min-replicas $(MinReplicas) --max-replicas $(MaxReplicas)  --ingress $(IngressType) --target-port $(IngressPort) --registry-server $(RegistryServer) --registry-username $(RegistryUsername) --registry-password $(RegistryPasswordSecretName)  --secrets $(PasswordSecretName)=$(RegistryPassword) --image  $(ContainerImage) --env-vars ENV_ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX=$(ENV_ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX) ENV_CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH=$(ENV_CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH)
```

To summarize it, get all VARIABLES with prefixed name ENV_ and pass it to --env-vars

Important addition: Not all variables are simple strings, some are json blobs and may contain spaces as well as unescaped quotes:

```
\"{\"type\":\"service_account\",\"project_id\":\"projectID\",\"private_key_id\":\"PRIVATEREGISTRYID\",\"private_key\":\"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nPRIVATEKEYHASH\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n\",\"client_email\":\"publisher@email.iam.gserviceaccount.com\",\"client_id\":\"11132670678102951289\",\"auth_uri\":\"https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/oauth2\/auth\",\"token_uri\":\"https:\/\/oauth2.googleapis.com\/token\",\"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\":\"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/oauth2\/v1\/certs\",\"client_x509_cert_url\":\"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/robot\/v1\/metadata\/x509\/az-fellipelli-publisher%40codescovery-default.iam.gserviceaccount.com\"}\"
```

## UPDATE

I've done some tests and so far I've ended up with the following approach

```bash
formatted_env_vars=$(env | grep '^ENV_' | while read -r line; do
  KEY=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 1)
  VALUE=$(echo "$line" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)
  echo "${KEY}=\"${VALUE}\""
done | tr '\n' ' ')
az containerapp create --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) --name $(ContainerAppName) --container-name $(ContainerAppName) --environment $(CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT) --cpu $(ContainerCpu) --memory $(ContainerMemory) --min-replicas $(MinReplicas) --max-replicas $(MaxReplicas)  --ingress $(IngressType) --target-port $(IngressPort) --registry-server $(RegistryServer) --registry-username $(RegistryUsername) --registry-password $(RegistryPasswordSecretName)  --secrets $(PasswordSecretName)=$(RegistryPassword) --image  $(ContainerImage) --env-vars ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX=$(ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX) CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH=$(CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH) "$formatted_env_vars"
```

This command results something like:

```bash
az containerapp create --resource-group my-resource-group --name my-app-name --container-name my-app-name --environment my-environment --cpu 0.25 --memory 0.5Gi --min-replicas 0 --max-replicas 1  --ingress external --target-port 80 --registry-server gcr.io --registry-username _json_key --registry-password secretref:registrypassword  --secrets registrypassword={"type":"service_account","project_id":"my-project-id","private_key_id":"ecd532a427a221bb5e95e6433a27723b25413392","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----n","client_email":"publisher@registry.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"2222035690768105943154","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/publisher%registry.iam.gserviceaccount.com"} --image  gcr.io/registry/codescovery/my-site-vue3:0.1.245274 --env-vars ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX=ENV_ CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH=/app/client/configurations/settings.json ENV_SITE_CREATOR_NAME="Example Creator" ENV_SITE_NAME="Site Name" ENV_SITE_TITLE="My Site Title"
```

But apparently it's writing the dynamically variables into **ENV_SITE_CREATOR_NAME** only:

[image: Azure Devops Log]

Here are the environment variables in **azure**

[image: Azure Devops Container Environment Variables]

What I'm missing?

## Update 2

According to [@siddheshdesai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20849135/siddheshdesai)
Answer I got the following result

[image: Aazure devops log]

[image: Container Instance]

Comment: powershell? bash?

Comment: Actually is an azure devops Release Task, it can be used wich can be used as `Type of script: PowerShell/PowerShell Core/Bat/Shell script. Select Shell/PowerShell Core script when running on Linux agent or Batch/PowerShell/PowerShell Core script when running on Windows agent. PowerShell Core script can run on cross-platform agents (Linux, macOS, or Windows).`

Comment: I know that, but do you have any preference? Is the current call in a PowerShell task? Are you on windows or on Linux? The reason I'm asking is because it's not really a azure-pipelines or azure-cli question, but a shell scripting question.

Comment: Adding tags for bash and powershell core, since it seems you have no preference. Removing `azure` as the Q isn't related to a true azure problem. Replacing azure-devops with azure-pipelines, since it's more precise.

Comment: Actually I don't have any preference, it's a Brand new release pipelines could be any one of them. I'll take a look at the answer you Just posted

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Environment variables in the Variables tab of Azure Release pipeline and then use it as an ENV_VAR in your pipeline, Refer below:-

[image]

And I used the same code as an environment variable in the inline script :-

```bash
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
az containerapp create --name $(ENV_ContainerAppName)  --resource-group $(ENV_ResourceGroupName) --cpu $(ENV_ContainerCpu) --memory $(ENV_ContainerMemory) --environment $(ENV_CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT)
```

And the container app got deployed successfully like below:-

[image]

[image]

You can also add the same variables in the Variable group and use those variable group across multiple pipeline within your Azure DevOps project, Refer below:-

[image]

And reference it in any pipeline like below:-

[image]

[image]

In order to call the Environment variables dynamically, you can make use of below CLI commands in your Azure CLI task:-

Code 1:-

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# set the prefix for your environment variables
envPrefix="ENV_"

# get the list of environment variables that have the specified prefix
envVars=$(env | grep "^$envPrefix" | sed "s/^$envPrefix//")

# create a string of environment variables in the format "KEY=VALUE"
envVarsStr=""
for envVar in $envVars; do
  envVarVal=$(eval "echo \$$envVar")
  envVarsStr+="$envVar=$envVarVal "
done

# create a string with the environment variables argument for the az command
envVarsArg="--env-vars $envVarsStr"

# set the extension configuration
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

# create the container app with the specified environment variables
az containerapp create --name $ContainerAppName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --cpu $ContainerCpu --memory $ContainerMemory --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT $envVarsArg
```

Code 2:-

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the prefix for your environment variables
envPrefix="ENV_"

# Retrieve environment variables dynamically
containerAppName=${!envPrefix"CONTAINERAPP_NAME"}
resourceGroupName=${!envPrefix"RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME"}
containerCpu=${!envPrefix"CONTAINER_CPU"}
containerMemory=${!envPrefix"CONTAINER_MEMORY"}
containerAppsEnvironment=${!envPrefix"CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT"}

# Retrieve environment variables that start with the prefix
envVars=()
while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
  envVars+=("$key=$value")
done < <(env | grep "^$envPrefix")

# Join the environment variables with a space
envVarsArg="--env-vars ${envVars[*]}"

# Set the Azure CLI extension configuration
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

# Create the Azure Container App
az containerapp create \
  --name "$containerAppName" \
  --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" \
  --cpu "$containerCpu" \
  --memory "$containerMemory" \
  --environment "$containerAppsEnvironment" \
  $envVarsArg
```

Above codes gets the required environment variables dynamically and sets them to the desired variables. Then it retrieves the variable that start with **"ENV_"** and joins them with space and creates **envVarsArg** variable. Then it uses Azure CLI extension config to create Azure container app with retrieved variable.

Output:-

[image]

[image]

Updated code:-

```
# set the prefix for your environment variables
envPrefix="ENV_"

# get the list of environment variables that have the specified prefix
envVars=$(env | grep "^$envPrefix" | sed "s/^$envPrefix//")

# create a string of environment variables in the format "KEY=VALUE"
envVarsStr=""
for envVar in $envVars; do
  envVarVal=$(eval "echo \$$envVar")
  
  # if the value of the environment variable contains spaces, enclose it in quotes
  if [[ "$envVarVal" == *" "* ]]; then
    envVarVal="\"$envVarVal\""
  fi
  
  envVarsStr+="$envVar=$envVarVal "
done

# create a string with the environment variables argument for the az command
envVarsArg="--env-vars $envVarsStr"

# set the extension configuration
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

# create the container app with the specified environment variables
az containerapp create --name $ContainerAppName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --cpu $ContainerCpu --memory $ContainerMemory --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT $envVarsArg
```

Updated code 2:-

```
# set the prefix for your environment variables
envPrefix="ENV_"

# get the list of environment variables that have the specified prefix
envVars=$(env | grep "^$envPrefix" | sed "s/^$envPrefix//")

# create an array of environment variables and their values
declare -a envVarsArr
for envVar in $envVars; do
  envVarVal=$(eval "echo \$$envVar")
  
  # if the value of the environment variable contains spaces, enclose it in quotes
  if [[ "$envVarVal" == *" "* ]]; then
    envVarVal="\"$envVarVal\""
  fi
  
  envVarsArr+=("$envVar=$envVarVal")
done

# join the elements of the array with spaces to create the envVarsStr variable
envVarsStr="${envVarsArr[@]}"

# create a string with the environment variables argument for the az command
envVarsArg="--env-vars $envVarsStr"

# set the extension configuration
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

# create the container app with the specified environment variables
az containerapp create --name $ContainerAppName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --cpu $ContainerCpu --memory $ContainerMemory --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT $envVarsArg
```

Comment: You didn't get the point of the question.

Comment: Manually I know How to do It. I need to get It dynamically, because I've too many variables(too many release pipelines) and I can't take the risk of missing one variable

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade Check the updated answer? I've added some additional commands that you can pass in your CLI to retrieve the value of Environment variables dynamically.

Comment: Sorry taking to long to answer, I wasn't in my development PC. Currently I'm getting the following error: `ERROR: Environment variables must be in the format "<key>=<value> <key>=secretref:<value> ..."`

Comment: Here is the --env-vars parameter `--env-vars ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX=ENV_ CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH=/app/client/configurations/settings.json ENV_SITE_CREATOR_NAME="TESTE CREATOR" ENV_SITE_NAME=Test ENV_SITE_DESCRIPTION=test`

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade Are the env variables in this format ? az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --environment-variables key1=value1 key2=value2'

Comment: Here is the --env-vars parameter part of the command `--env-vars ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX=ENV_ CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH=/app/client/configurations/settings.json ENV_SITE_CREATOR_NAME="TESTE CREATOR" ENV_SITE_NAME=Test ENV_SITE_DESCRIPTION=test`

Comment: I think the main problem is the variable ENV_SITE_CREATOR_NAME. But in docs the say we can pass a variable with KEY="VALUE"

Comment: Looking at your assignment to `formatted_env_vars` you find your vars with `grep`, then split them on `=` and then immediately recombine them with `echo` ?

As far as I can tell, the only thing that actually does something is the `tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: The tr '\n' ' ' command removes any new line characters from the final envVarsStr

Comment: Can you try this command- envVarsStr=""
for envVar in $envVars; do
  envVarVal=$(eval "echo \$$envVar")
  
  # if the value of the environment variable contains spaces, enclose it in quotes
  if [[ "$envVarVal" == *" "* ]]; then
    envVarVal="\"$envVarVal\""
  fi
  
  envVarsStr+="$envVar=$envVarVal "
done

# create a string with the environment variables argument for the az command
envVarsArg="--env-vars $envVarsStr"

Comment: and then this - # set the extension configuration
az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt

# create the container app with the specified environment variables
az containerapp create --name $ContainerAppName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --cpu $ContainerCpu --memory $ContainerMemory --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT $envVarsArg

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade Added the updated code in my answer

Comment: I've tested your answer, It's very close to what i need. but when the variable value contains spaces it is getting loss.

Comment: I'm updating the question so yo can see the results

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade Check the Updated code 2 in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with some information regarding your answer

Comment: @ViniciusAndrade I have updated a new code in my answer at last refer Updated code 2? Did you try that to avoid the space loss?

Comment: Yes, as I posted in the updated question: it's creating the variables the wrong way. Please take a look in ** Update 2 ** in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252755/discussion-between-vinicius-andrade-and-siddheshdesai).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get all environment variables with prefix "ENV_"
# Initialize variable
ENV_VARS=""

# Loop through all environment variables
while IFS= read -r var
do
  # Check if the variable starts with ENV_
  if [[ "$var" == ENV_* ]]; then
    # Extract the variable name and value
    name=$(echo "$var" | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sed 's/^//')
    value=$(echo "$var" | cut -d '=' -f 2-)

    # Escape any single quotes in the value
    value="${value//\'/\'\\\'\'}"

    # Append the variable and its value to the result
    ENV_VARS+=" $name='$value'"
  fi
done <<< "$(env)"

# Create the container app in Azure
echo "Creating container app $CONTAINERAPP_NAME in Azure..."
az containerapp create \
  --name $CONTAINERAPP_NAME \
  --resource-group my_resource_group \
  --image $IMAGE_NAME \
  --env-vars $ENV_VARS
```

Comment: Didn't work, but I think this is something like this.  I couldn't use the `<(echo "$ENV_VARS")` command, I used just `"$ENV_VARS"` . And this is the output of the command writing the envirionment variables to the container:
`"value": "creator\nENV_SITE_NAME=Test\nENV_SITE_TITLE=\"testeeeer a\""`

Comment: probably need a bit of fine tuning the command.. will have a look

Comment: try the updated command - that may work

Comment: Just triggered the pipeline, It will take about 5 minutes to finish. 
Can we move this to a chat? I think would be better to sharing logs and images

Comment: Now I've got the following error: ` ERROR: Environment variables must be in the format "<key>=<value> <key>=secretref:<value> ..."`

Comment: This problem apparently happens when I try to set a multi string value to a variable, like: **ENV_SITE_TITLE="testeeeer a"** but according to this command: `az containerapp create -n MyContainerapp -g MyResourceGroup \
    --image my-app:v1.0 --environment MyContainerappEnv \
    --secrets mysecret=secretvalue1 anothersecret="secret value 2" \
    --env-vars GREETING="Hello, world" SECRETENV=secretref:anothersecret` 
From [Microsfot Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-create) this is possible

Comment: updated answer to take care of space in the environment variable value

Comment: Still having the same problem. Did you try running it with a multi word string?

I've just printed the command used, here is the final results

`az containerapp create --resource-group non-production --name site --container-name site3 --environment non-production --cpu 0.25 --memory 0.5Gi --min-replicas 0 --max-replicas 1  --ingress external --target-port 80  --image imageName --env-vars ENVIRONMENT_NAME_PREFIX=ENV_ CLIENT_CONFIG_PATH=/app/client/configurations/settings.json ENV_SITE_CREATOR_NAME=creator ENV_SITE_NAME=Test ENV_SITE_TITLE="testeeeer a"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252597/discussion-between-vinicius-andrade-and-scorpio).

Answer (score 1):

In powershell, you can grab all the environment variables and then buid the string with which you call the azure cli:

```
gci env:*
```

Filtering that down to all variables starting with `ENV_`:

```
gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }
```

That leaves us with building the string to pass to azure-cli:

```
((gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }) | %{ "$($_.name)=$($_.value)" }) -join " "
```

And then we're left with the quoting issue. I'm not 100% sure how azure-cli wants its quotes, "abc=def ghi" or abc="def ghi", but that's easy to add in:

```
# either: "abc=def ghi"
((gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }) | %{ "`"$($_.name)=$($_.value)`"" }) 

# Or abc="def ghi"
((gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }) | %{ "$($_.name)=`"$($_.value)`"" })
```

Then call azure-cli:

```
& az containerapp create `
   --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) `
   --name $(ContainerAppName) `
   --container-name $(ContainerAppName) `
   --environment $(CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT) `
   --cpu $(ContainerCpu) --memory $(ContainerMemory) `
   --min-replicas $(MinReplicas) --max-replicas $(MaxReplicas)  `
   --ingress $(IngressType) `
   --target-port $(IngressPort) `
   --registry-server $(RegistryServer) --registry-username $(RegistryUsername) --registry-password $(RegistryPasswordSecretName) `
   --secrets "$(PasswordSecretName)=$(RegistryPassword)" `
   --image  $(ContainerImage) `
   --env-vars ((gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }) | %{ "`"$($_.name)=$($_.value)`"" })
```

Or [build the *whole string* and then calling it through invoke-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338047/736079):

```
$envVars = ((gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }) | %{ "`"$($_.name)=$($_.value)`"" }) -join " "
$command = "& az containerapp create `
   --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) `
   --name $(ContainerAppName) `
   --container-name $(ContainerAppName) `
   --environment $(CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT) `
   --cpu $(ContainerCpu) --memory $(ContainerMemory) `
   --min-replicas $(MinReplicas) --max-replicas $(MaxReplicas)  `
   --ingress $(IngressType) `
   --target-port $(IngressPort) `
   --registry-server $(RegistryServer) --registry-username $(RegistryUsername) --registry-password $(RegistryPasswordSecretName) `
   --secrets `"$(PasswordSecretName)=$(RegistryPassword)`" `
   --image $(ContainerImage) `
   --env-vars $envVars"

iex $command # invoke expression
```

To pass variables to Powershell in a safer manner, you can use:

```
- powershell: |
      & az .... $env:RegistryUsername
    env:
      RegistryUsername: $(RegistryUsername)
```

Or in UI based pipelines and releases:

[image: Pass variables through the environment section]

This usually simplifies many of the quoting issues since PowerShell will know how to pass the contents of the variable safely to the invocation of `az`, where as when you inline the azure pipelines variable reference, the contents will be added to the script without context. I'm not aware of any clear docs on the dangers, but here's a [doc from the GitHub Actions team that explains the potential issue. This applies to Azure Pipelines as well](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#understanding-the-risk-of-script-injections).

Comment: by the way, do all of these things have to be an Azure Pipelines variable? I wonder whether some of these values could simply be hard-coded in the script just to make things easier.

Comment: I prefer to be in pipeline, so I don't have to mantain a separated script file and commit the code everytime I need to change it.

Comment: I've just ran the script using `--env-vars ((gci env:* | ?{ $_.name -like "ENV_*" }) | %{ "\`"$($_.name)=$($_.value)\`"" }) -join " " and I got the following Error:  `ERROR: unrecognized arguments: -join `

Comment: Then I added a () to wrap the command and got the following message: `ERROR: Secrets must be in format "<key>=<value> <key>=<value> ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252605/discussion-between-vinicius-andrade-and-jessehouwing).