# Powershell: inconsistent/strange behavior with quote parsing?

Tags: parsing, powershell, double-quotes

all! I'm trying to compile a program using PowerShell, but the command is being parsed strangely. 
This command executes correctly in cmd.exe:

```
dmd -od"bin" -of"bin\convHull.exe" -I"src" "src\concSort.d" "src\fileParser.d" "src\main.d" "src\pointLogic.d" "src\quickHull.d" "src\stupidHull.d" -D -O -release
```

But PowerShell executes it as: (***blue***, **navy**, *purple* texts as they appear in PowerShell ISE)

***dmd*** **-od"bin" -of"bin\convHull***.exe" -I"src" "src\concSort.d" "src\fileParser.d" "src\main.d" "src\pointLogic.d" "src\quickHull.d" "src\stupidHull.d" -D -O -release*

This spits the following error:

```
The string starting:
At line:1 char:147
+ dmd -od"bin" -of"bin\convHull.exe" -I"src" "src\concSort.d" "src\fileParser.d" "src\main.d"     
"src\pointLogic.d" "src\quickHull.d" "src\stupidHull.d <<<< " -D -O -release
is missing the terminator: ".
At line:1 char:163
```

So it seems to be interpreting a period as a quote. This is peculiar. Has anyone else had this problem with PowerShell?

Things I've tried:

1. escaping quotes
2. making sure all quotes are "straight quotes" and not angled
3. putting a space before quotes (parses correctly, but the program doesn't understand the arguments.)

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: +1 for engaging in D language :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick (newlines added for clarity only, and removal of extra quotes):

```
dmd '-od"bin"' '-of"bin\convHull.exe"' '-I"src"'
    src\concSort.d src\fileParser.d src\main.d src\pointLogic.d src\quickHull.d src\stupidHull.d
    -D -O -release
```

Note that in the case where a quote (") is to *be passed as part of the argument itself*, I surrounded the entire argument with single quotes ('). From the experimentation below it can be seen that *only* `-of"..."` needs the quotes about it.

Happy coding.

---

I can't find a good reference on this exact production, however note the following parsings:

```
-x"w."   ->  error: " expected (last " is special)
-x"w.""  ->  -x"w and ."" (the . starts a new token and the " in that starts
                           a quote; however, the quotes are not removed)
'-x"w."' ->  -x"w." (extra quote fine, neither special)
-x"w"    ->  -x"w"  (no . and " not special)
-x"w""   ->  -x"w"" (no . and " not special)
a".b"    ->  a.b    (didn't start with `-`, quotes removed)
a".b     ->  error: " expected (" is special)
```

So it does indeed appear to have something to do with the `.` and `-` combination (and it might not be exclusive). From the above I believe that a token starting with `-` *does not* include the `.` character as a valid character in the token so the lexer terminates said token and starts a new token -- easily provable with a good EBNF reference, which I don't have.

---

The best I can find is [Appendix C: The PowerShell Grammar](http://www.manning.com/payette/AppCexcerpt.pdf):

> > The ParameterToken rule is used to match cmdlet parameters such as -foo or -
> >     boolProp: . Note that this rule will also match --foobar, so this rule has
> >     to be checked before the  --token rule.

```
<ParameterToken> = -[:letter:]+[:]{0 |1}
```

However, this is incomplete at best and does not even include a definition of "letter".

Comment: Excellent answer.  I am somewhat surprised by the 4th and 5th examples.  I'll have to study the parser some more.  Maybe it is the lack of punctuation?

Comment: @JasonMArcher The " in the 4th and 5th examples *isn't* special because it is part of the token that begins with `-`. It appears, however, that the `.` character will terminate a token starting with `-`. I was taken back by the 6th example (after sorting out the `.` business) because I didn't realize the quotes would be just *removed* (as the quotes do not begin the token and the result is still a single token). It really would be if Microsoft published the official (and complete) grammar/tokenizing rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the executable, but this seems to want to work.

```
 $cmd = @'
 dmd -od"bin" -of"bin\convHull.exe" -I"src" "src\concSort.d" "src\fileParser.d" "src\main.d" "src\pointLogic.d" "src\quickHull.d" "src\stupidHull.d" -D -O -release
 '@

 &$cmd
```