# powershell: script to start a program with parameters?

Tags: powershell, authentication, group-policy, invoke-command

When i run the Powershell script below i receive the error below. How do i run programs through powershell with parameters? The script will be a group policy logon.

> Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that
>   accepts argument '\TBHSERVER\NETLOGON\BGInfo\BGIFILE.bgi /timer:0 /s
>   ilent /nolicprompt '. At
>   X:\Systems\scripts\PowerShell\UpdateDesktopWithBGInfo.ps1:6 char:18
>   + Invoke-Expression <<<<  $logonpath $ArguList
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

```
$LogonPath = $env:LOGONSERVER + "\NETLOGON\BGInfo\Bginfo.exe" 
$ArguList = $env:LOGONSERVER + '\NETLOGON\BGInfo\BGIFILE.bgi /timer:0 /silent /nolicprompt '
invoke-command $LogonPath
Invoke-Expression $logonpath $ArguList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
& "\\$env:LOGONSERVER\NETLOGON\BGInfo\Bginfo.exe" "\\$env:LOGONSERVER\NETLOGON\BGInfo\BGIFILE.bgi" /timer:0 /silent /nolicprompt
```

If the BGIFILE.bgi reside in the same location as Bginfo.exe then you can specify only the file name:

```
& "\\$env:LOGONSERVER\NETLOGON\BGInfo\Bginfo.exe" BGIFILE.bgi /timer:0 /silent /nolicprompt
```

Comment: Thanks, works a treat :-) I just needed to change the 2nd path to include a $envLogonserver, thought i would include the final command in-case anyone needs to run the same command. 

 "& "$env:LOGONSERVER\NETLOGON\BGInfo\Bginfo.exe" "$env:LOGONSERVER\NETLOGON\BGInfo\default.bgi" /timer:0 /silent /nolicprompt"

Comment: @resolver101 - If it worked, you should Accept the answer. Click on the tick next to the answer. ( and work on accepting answers for your other questions)

Comment: @resolver101 You can shorten the path if the .bgi file resides in the same location as bginfo.exe. I will update my answer

Answer (score 7):

`Invoke-Command` is best suited for running commands remotely. As Shay points out you can use the ampersand `&` to tell PowerShell to execute something locally just like the cmd.exe shell.

In order to make `Invoke-Command` work you would need to do something like this:

```
$program = "C:\windows\system32\ping.exe"
$programArgs = "localhost", "-n", 1
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & $program $programArgs }
```

Notice the use of the the ampersand in the script block. So if you are running a command locally just use the ampersand as Shay's example shows.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Im learning powershell so all the information im soking up all the info you guys can throw at me :-)