# Powershell: run msiexec with dynamically created parameters

Tags: scripting, powershell, windows-installer

in my powershell script, I need to run msiexec and pass few parameters to initialize it. The problem is, that if a parameter contains space character " ", powershell doesn't execute msiexec correctly. For example the command:

```
msiexec /i .\Setup.msi ConnectionString="Initial Catalog=something;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
```

The parameter ConnectionString contains spaces, and this causes that msiexec is not executed correctly, I get msiexec error code 1639 - Invalid command line argument. If I remove spaces from from connection string, msiexec is executed correctly.

Do anybody have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: could you try this: msiexec /i .\Setup.msi 'ConnectionString="Initial Catalog=something;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"'

Comment: I try it, unfortunatelly, it doesn't work, but thanks for idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList / /i, .\Setup.msi, "ConnectionString='Initial Catalog=something;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False'"  -Wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Try single quoting it like this:

```
& msiexec.exe /i .\Setup.msi ConnectionString='"Initial Catalog=something;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"'
```