# Quote Madness in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using `invoke-expression` in PowerShell to create an archive, but it's not working due to spaces in the exe path. These are my variables:

```
Set-Variable -name DIRRELEASE       -value (Join-Path $env:UserProfile "\Documents\Coding\_Projects\ChickenPing\trunk\Dist\current\")
$srcPath = (Join-Path $DIRRELEASE ("myapp_1.90-src.zip"))
Set-Variable -name WinRarFilter     -value "-x*\.svn -x*\.svn\* -x*\nutrition.db3"
Set-Variable -name WinRarOpts       -value "-r -s -m5 -inul"
$WinRar = `"C:\Program Files\Winrar\winrar.exe`"

#Then using this to invoke:
Invoke-Expression ($WinRAR + " a " + $srcPath + " " + $WinRARFilter + " * " + $WinRAROpts)
```

When I run the script I get this error:

> The term 'a' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included,  verify that the path is correct and try
>   again. At line:1 char:3
>   +  a <<<<  C:\Users\Echilon\Documents\Coding_Projects\MyApp\trunk\Dist\c
>   urrent\myapp_1.95-src.zip -x*.svn -x*.svn* -x*\nutrition.db3 * -r
>   -s - m5 -inul
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (a:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx    ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I just can't find the right combination of quotes and plusses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make this a lot easier to work with by using the call operator `&`.

```
& $WinRAR a $srcPath "-x*\.svn" "-x*\.svn\*" "-x*\nutrition.db3" *  -r -s -m5 -inul
```

Comment: Command invocation operator is definitely the way to go. If you really want to stick with Invoke-Expression, you could try the format operator (-f) to get your quoting right [untested code follows]: '"{0}" a "{1}" {2} * {3}' -f $WinRar,$srcPath,$WinRARFilter,$WinRAROpts

Comment: I never really get why people always try `iex` when calling other programs. Or some even more convoluted ways ... heck, it's a *shell* (not only by name) – its primary purpose is to call commands and programs.

Comment: I've only found `iex` useful if I have something I want to execute in a text file.

Comment: I usually find an expandable here-string easier to work with than using -f for getting the quoting right. Put whatever kind of quotes you want, whereever you want them, and you don't have to worry about nesting or escaping.

Comment: Unless you need to include a variable with a property. Then you either need to use a subexpression + double quoted here-string or -f on the here-string.

Comment: Yes.  But even with the sub-expression, it's more intuitive to read that going back and forth between the format string and the argument list, IMHO.

Comment: Pros and cons. Pro: re-factoring is easier (somewhat of a pain to insert a new string formatter because you have to go back and change all the targets {#}). Con: lose syntax highlighting and intellisense (its all a string so it's more difficult to identify a syntax error).

Comment: I can see losing syntax highlighting as being an isseue.  When you're creating command strings for an external command, it's unlikely itellisense would recognize the command and it's parameters and required syntax anyway, so you didn't lose much there.

Comment: What an absolute nightmare, after much experimenting, I got it to work with:
`& $WinRAR a $zipPath "-x*\.svn" "-x*\.svn\*" "-x*\nutrition.db3" ($DistName + "-zip") -r -s -m5 -inul`