# Opening WSL2 distro in Windows Terminal and running a command using Command Prompt

Tags: linux, windows, wsl-2, windows-terminal

I'd like to open a new (Ubuntu) WSL2 session in Windows Terminal and run a command in it using a script or just a single line of code in Windows Command Prompt.

It seems pretty hard to me. I only got to this:

`wt -w 0 nt -p "Ubuntu" -d \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home`

where `-w 0` tells to create a new tab in existing WT windows (if already present), `nt` is new-tab command (can be omitted), `-p <>` indicates the profile to run, `-d <>` the starting directory.

But how to pass a command to run?

Answer (score 3):

I find it best to have `wt` launch the `wsl.exe` command itself, since it has the best "control" over how things are started inside it.

The main issue is typically going to be quoting/escaping.

But let's start with an example that (should) work from the Windows "Run" dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), PowerShell, or CMD:

```
wt -w 0 nt -p Ubuntu wsl.exe ~ -e bash -c "ls\; sleep 5"
```

Explanation:

- This uses the "Ubuntu" profile, but overrides the profile's `commandLine` setting with the rest of the line.
- As you noted, the `nt` (new-tab) here is optional.
- The `wsl.exe ~` starts in your home directory.  You could also use `--cd /home` if you wanted to replicate the `-d \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home` you are trying in your question.
- The `-e bash` starts the Bash shell, passing in ...
- `-c "ls\; sleep 5"` to run an `ls` command wait 5 seconds before exiting the shell (and likely the tab).

---

Other options/notes:

- Quoting/escaping is always a bit painful when handing off from CMD (or PowerShell) to WSL/Linux.  Note the use of `\;` to escape the semicolon between bash commands.
- You could set up a profile with the *"Profile Termination Behavior"* set to *"Never close automatically"* and avoid the `sleep`.
- The following also works well:

  ```
  wt -w 0 nt -p Ubuntu wsl.exe ~ -e bash -c "ls\; exec bash"
  ```

  This runs the command (`ls` in this case) and then starts a new Bash shell (replacing the current one) that *won't* terminate until you exit it.
- From PowerShell, another quoting option is to use a [here string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296076/11810933):

  ```
  wt -w 0 nt -p Ubuntu wsl.exe ~ -e bash -c @"
    ls
    exec bash
  "@
  ```

Comment: Ok thank you SO much, now it's definitely clearer. And what about passing a ubuntu cmd as python3 myscript.py? Does this way of proceeding make any sense? I'd like to have a set of python programs running (indefinitely) at startup instead of (each time) starting them manually. Thank you

Comment: @StefanoFabbri Sure!  Just do `wsl.exe ~ -e python3 /path/to/myscript.py`.