# Powershell command line argument with spaces and curly brackets?

Tags: powershell

I am making an attempt at my first powershell script and getting a bad parameter error when running the following code. How can I pass the argument to the command in powersehll?

```
& "bcdedit" /store c:\boot\bcd /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:
```

**EDIT:**
The working code for this is:

```
& "bcdedit" /store c:\boot\bcd /set "{bootmgr}" device partition=C:
```

Comment: can you please post the exact error message[s] ?

Comment: An unknown command was specified. Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.

Comment: Figured it out. the {bootmgr} needs double quotes around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curly brackets threw everything off. Putting quotes around `{bootmgr}` fixed the problem.

```
& "bcdedit" /store c:\boot\bcd /set "{bootmgr}" device partition=C:
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are running into is that the PowerShell parser works differently than the `cmd.exe` parser does. One way around this is to pass your command to `cmd.exe` and let it do the parsing.

To do this, pass the command to `cmd.exe` using the `/c` option as a single-quoted string.

```
cmd.exe /c 'bcdedit /store c:\boot\bcd /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:'
```

This method is especially useful when the command you are using requires string-quoted arguments.

Comment: This is a great solution for so many issues with Powershell (especially if you are already invested in the old command line)