# Missing argument -m using svn at windows powershell

Tags: windows, svn, powershell, command-line

I'm trying to run this at Windows PowerShell:

```
svn ci -m "" directory_name
```

but it returns:

> svn: E205005: The log message is a pathname (was -F intended?); use
>   '--force-log' to override

i tried to cd that directory and commit without directory_name argument, and it retuns:

```
svn ci -m ""
```

> svn.exe: missing argument: m

i think that powershell maybe doesn't understand -args but rarely (to me) this works:

```
svn -h
```

Am i doing something wrong? All this at cmd works perfectly :/

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
svn ci -m '""' directory_name
```

or

```
svn ci -m `"`" directory_name
```

PowerShell's argument passing to native programs is a bit weird sometimes and this is another edge case that's frustrating.

Comment: Works perfect, and yes, it's frustrating to escape quotes hehe Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell strips the first set of double quotes as it tries to expand its content and the underlying command gets nothing. 
I wonder if this works as well (I don't use svn).

svn ci -m ([string]::Empty)