# Problems using powershell to perform a source safe get by label

Tags: powershell, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I'm trying to use powershell to do a "get" from srcSafe using a label that contains spaces.

I've read what seems like numerous posts about how to pass params w/spaces to exe's but nothing I've tried works.  My problem appears to be supplying the label correctly.

Following is the cmd line version ( which works ).

```
ss get $/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/* -R -I-N -VL"label space"
```

My simplest powershell version is:

```
ss get '$/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/*' -R -I-N '-VL\"label space\"'
```

When I run the powershell cmd I get no files and $lastexitcode is "100".

Echo args shows what I think should be correct.

```
Arg 0 is <get>
Arg 1 is <$/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/*>
Arg 2 is <-R>
Arg 3 is <-I-N>
Arg 4 is <-VL"label space">
```

Powershell ISE shows the same.

```
DEBUG: NativeCommandParameterBinder Information: 0 :  WriteLine   Raw argument string:  get $/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/* -R -I-N "-VL\"label space\""
DEBUG: NativeCommandParameterBinder Information: 0 :  WriteLine   Argument 0: get
DEBUG: NativeCommandParameterBinder Information: 0 :  WriteLine   Argument 1: $/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/*
DEBUG: NativeCommandParameterBinder Information: 0 :  WriteLine   Argument 2: -R
DEBUG: NativeCommandParameterBinder Information: 0 :  WriteLine   Argument 3: -I-N
DEBUG: NativeCommandParameterBinder Information: 0 :  WriteLine   Argument 4: -VL"label space"
```

Just to confuse things start-process seems to work:

```
$cmd = "ss.exe"
$args = "get", '$/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/*', "-R", "-I-N", '-VL"label space"'
$proc = start-process $cmd $args -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru -WorkingDir $pwd
$proc.ExitCode
```

An additional confusing item is the fact the echo args now shows the version parameter as:
Arg 4 is <-VLlabel space>   -> note no spaces, also does not work from cmd line.

Thanx for any help!

John A.

Comment: With start-process you do not use \ to escape " and it works fine for you - have you tried to do the same with regular call: `ss get '$/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/*' -R -I-N '-VL"label space"'` ?

Comment: When I try the following:
ss.exe get '$/sandbox/TestSSCmdLine/*' '-R' '-I-N' '-VL"label space"'
ss fails and I get an error message: "space is not an existing filename or project"
echoargs shows the following
Arg 5 is <-VLlabel>
Arg 6 is <space>

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd`, the quotes would have been used to ensure `label space` was passed as a part of the `-VL` argument. Since the `Start-Process` version works with a result argument of `-VLlabel space`, I would try calling `ss` with `'-VLlabel space'`, without any embedded quotes (third option listed at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468690/2495)).