# Call ruby script from powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell

i have following situation:
a powershell script with this variables:

```
$RUBY = "C:\installing\ruby\bin\ruby.exe"
$ARGS = "C:\files\sript.rb $Arg1 $Arg2 $Arg3"
```

in a batch file i can write

```
%RUBY% %ARGS%
```

and it works.

but how can i do this in powershell?

It is important that the ruby installing path is variable.

I tried it with Start-Process but only ruby.exe was started, without script.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `$RUBY $ARGS` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `$args` is an [automatic variable](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113212) managed by PowerShell, so I would avoid trying to declare your own variable with the same name.

To invoke a command stored in a variable from PowerShell, you can use the [call operator `&`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113242):

```powershell
& $ruby 'script.rb'
```

If you need to build up the list of arguments, I would recommend creating an array, instead of mashing them all together into a single string:

```powershell
$rubyArgs = @('C:\files\script.rb', $Arg1, $Arg2, $Arg3)
& $ruby $rubyArgs
```

If you need to pass more complicated arguments, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468690/2495) useful.

Comment: Thank you - this helped me with getting my ruby script, which ran fine while in a powershell window on a vm, to run correctly when executing in a jenkins job using the powershell plugin.