# Invoke executable (w/parameters) from powershell script

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm calling a zip utility from powershell and having a difficult time getting its parameters straight.  Here's the code:

```
    if (-not (test-path "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
    set-alias sz "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

    $argument_1 = "c:\temp\DeployTemp\"
    $argument_0 = "c:\temp\Release\Web_Feature_2012R10_1_1112.prod.com.zip"

    sz x $argument_0 -o$argument_1
```

The problem is the 7zip executable call literally extracts to a directory named $argument_1, instead of the actual value stored in the string.  I've tried escaping the value in a few ways but without luck. Unfortunately the 7zip "-o" flag can't have a space between it and the output directory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
& "$sz" x $argument_0 "-o$argument_1"
```

The ampersand tells PowerShell to treat the expression more like CMD.exe would, but still allow for the variable expansion (tokens that start with a $).

Comment: Thank you.  The update that worked for me was & sz x $argument_0 "-o$argument_1"

Comment: The ampersand does nothing to cause behavior "closer to cmd."  It merely indicates to powershell that the upcoming *string* should be interpreted as a *command*.  This allows the user to invoke executables or scripts via a full path with spaces or special characters.  There is no effect on the remaining arguments.

Comment: The fix was simply to get the escaping right.  The final argument just needs to be `"-o$argument_1"` as double quotes allow for variable expansion.  The full command could be `sz x $argument_0 "-o$argument_1"`