# Parameters with double quotes are not properly passed to Scriptblock by ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm writing generic powershell script to perform deployments on remote machines. I have hit one problem I can not overrun, and this problem is with parameters with double quotes in Scriptblock passed by ArgumentList

I have something like this:

```
$remoteAddress = "some-pc"
$deploymentCommand = "D:\some path\Command.exe"
$deploymentPackages = @(`"“package - one - external"`", `"“package - two - external"`", `"“package - three - internal"`")

foreach ($deploymentPackage in $deploymentPackages)
{
invoke-command -ComputerName $remoteAddress -ScriptBlock { param ($deployCmd, $deployPackage) &  $deployCmd -package:$deployPackage -action:doit } -ArgumentList   $deploymentCommand,$deploymentPackage
}
```

I have added double quotes in $deploymentPackages. And still I'm getting my command executed remotly like this (which of course fails):

```
D:\some path\Command.exe -package:package - one - external -action:doit
D:\some path\Command.exe -package:package - two - external -action:doit
D:\some path\Command.exe -package:package - three - external -action:doit
```

while proper execution path should be:

```
D:\some path\Command.exe -package:"package - three - external" -action:doit
```

without quotes around package - one - external which mess up everythig

How to overrun this problem, because i have tested number of solutions and non of them worked.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$remoteAddress = "some-pc"
$deploymentCommand = "D:\some path\Command.exe"
$deploymentPackages = @('package - one - external', 'package - two - external', 'package - three - internal')
$remoteScript = {
    param( $deployCmd, $deployPackage )
    & $deployCmd "-package:$deployPackage" -action:doit
}

foreach ($deploymentPackage in $deploymentPackages)
{
   invoke-command -ComputerName $remoteAddress -ScriptBlock $remoteScript -ArgumentList $deploymentCommand,$deploymentPackage
}
```

This bundles `-package:<some string here>` into a single argument when passed to your executable, which is the same as doing something like `-package:"aaa bbb ccc"` in cmd.exe.

I assume you don't want literal quotes passed to the exe, just for `-package:<some string here>` to be a single argument regardless of spaces in `<some string here>`

If you want literal quotes to be passed to the exe, use the above code with

```
& $deployCmd "-package:`"$deployPackage`"" -action:doit
```

Answer (score 8):

You can fix this by using single quotes to wrap your strings. With single quotes, the content between the quotes will be untouched(variables won't expand and signs like quotes will be kept). E.g.

```
PS > '"this is a test"'
"this is a test"
```

So to fix your script, try replacing your `deploymentpackages` array with this:

```
$deploymentPackages = @('"package - one - external"', '"package - two - external"', '"package - three - internal"')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using single quotes around the string with the double quotes. I simplified the script a little bit to just write the string instead of running it.

```
$remoteAddress = "some-pc";
$deploymentPackages = @('"package - one - external"', '"package - two - external"', '"package - three - internal"');

foreach ($deploymentPackage in $deploymentPackages)
{
    invoke-command -ComputerName $remoteAddress -ScriptBlock {
        param ($deploymentPackage) write-host ("-package:{0} -action:doit" -f $deploymentPackage); 
    } -ArgumentList   $deploymentPackage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"""`. For example,

```
$Var = "One"
```

`$Var` will display `One`.

While `"""$Var"""` will display `One`

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem when trying to send an email from a PowerShell script called from a DOS script. I have lost some time to find the following solution.

DOS Script

```
set MSG="US-TrackingFile has been copied to Z: drive"
call SendMail.bat %MSG%
```

SendMail.bat DOS script

```
PowerShell.exe .\SendMail.ps1 '"%1"'
```

SendMail.ps1 PowerShell script

```
$msg = $args[0]

Send-MailMessage
  -to "bernard_schleich@atos.net" 
  -subject "$msg" 
  -smtpserver emearelay.ec.company.com 
  -from "windows.system@company.com"
```

The following solution without calling intermediary DOS script work also

```
set MSG="\"US-TrackingFile has been copied to Z: drive\""
PowerShell.exe .\SendMail.ps1 %MSG%
```

but is a little tricky because you must add \" at start and end of each message.

In all cases, the title of my message is correctly displayed without double quote at start and end of message :-)