# Using --% in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've seen `--%` referenced in relation to executing a command with multiple parameters. I'm having trouble googling for more information about it. I suspect Google thinks I'm trying a special syntax. I'm hoping to be able to execute the plink command from PowerShell and using variables to add the parameters like this:

```
&"./plink.exe" --% $Hostname -l $Username -pw $Password $Command
```

It works if I specify the information, but not with variable substitution.

Comment: Actually you can work with this situation. See my answer below. I figured out a workaround the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had this same problem, and there is a workaround for this problem. I recently blogged about this (*[Use PowerShell variables after escaping parsing in PowerShell v3.0](http://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2013/09/use-powershell-variables-after-escaping.html)*  - 2013-09-17) after taking inspiration from my own answer, *[Executing external command from PowerShell is not accepting a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745811/powershell-executing-external-command-not-accepting-parameter/18746861#18746861)*.

The trick is to use `--%` itself as a variable and include that along with other variables in PowerShell.

So instead of this,

```
&"./plink.exe" --% $Hostname -l $Username -pw $Password $Command
```

try this:

```
$escapeparser = '--%'
& "./plink.exe" $escapeparser $Hostname -l $Username -pw $Password $Command
```

It may be related, but I used single quotes in all variables.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar:

&"./plink.exe" "--%" "$hostname -l $username -pw $password -batch replication status"

This gave me the output right out of the command line

Answer (score 14):

I also [blogged about this](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/powershell-v3-ctp2-provides-better-argument-passing-to-exes/) shortly after v3 shipped.  `--%` turns PowerShell into a dumb parser from that character sequence until the end of the line.  That means you don't get any variable evaluation after `--%`..  However, you case use environment variables like so:

```
$env:hostname = $hostname
$env:user     = $user
$env:passwd   = $password
$env:command  = $command
.\plink.exe --% %hostname% -l %user% -pw %passwd% %Command%
```

That said, in this scenario I don't see any reason to use --%.  This should work just fine:

```
.\plink.exe $Hostname -l $Username -pw $Password $Command
```

You only want to use `--%` when the EXE's command line arguments expect arguments with characters that trip up PowerShell e.g.:

```
tf.exe status . /r /workspace:*;domain\user
```

In this case, tf.exe uses `;` to separate the workspace name from the workspace owner but PowerShell interprets the `;` as a statement separator which messes up the invocation of tf.exe.  You would fix it like so:

```
tf.exe status . /r --% /workspace:*;domain\user
```

BTW the use of `&` is unnecessary here because you don't need to quote `.\plink.exe'.  You would only need to quote it if the filename or path contained a space.

Answer (score 8):

`--%` will prevent the remainder of a statement from being parsed by PowerShell. [Jose Barreto's Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters.aspx) on TechNet has a very relevant entry to this problem. Along with providing example usage of `--%`, there are others, such as `cmd /c`, which may be more helpful for solving your issue since PowerShell not resolving variables after `--%` seems problematic for your use case.

`--%` is new in PowerShell version 3.

Some example usage from the linked blog:

```
PS C:\> ICACLS.EXE --% C:\TEST /GRANT USERS:(F)
processed file: C:\TEST
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

PS C:\> ICACLS.EXE C:\TEST --% /GRANT USERS:(F)
processed file: C:\TEST
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

As I mentioned above, you would probably be better off trying a solution where you can use PowerShell variables. `& " "` or `cmd /c " "` will both resolve variables and may be a good place to start.

```
cmd /c "path/plink.exe $Hostname -l $Username -pw $Password $Command"
```

---

I was digging around in the [PowerShell Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389) for something unrelated and found some documentation for `--%`.  I'll post it here in the hopes that it will be easier to find online for future users:

> Excerpt from 8.2 "Pipeline statements"
>
> An argument of --% indicates that all arguments following it are to be
>   passed with minimal parsing and processing. This argument is called
>   the verbatim parameter. Arguments after the verbatim parameter are not
>   PowerShell expressions even if they are syntactically valid PowerShell
>   expressions.
>
> Windows PowerShell: If the command type is Application, the parameter
>   --% is not passed to the command. The arguments after --% have any environment variables (strings surrounded by %) expanded. For example:
>
> echoargs.exe --% "%path%"  # %path% is replaced with the value
>   $env:path