# PowerShell or CMD errors on space in file path

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a PowerShell script that installs some stuff. It's erroring where it tries to call an .exe file that has a path with a space in the name:

```
try
{
    cmd /c "C:\Program Files\myfile.exe" -i "C:\myconfig.sql"
}
```

The error it provides is:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Why is it tripping up on the space in the file path when I enclose the path in quotes?

Comment: `cmd /c "C:\Program Files\myfile.exe" -i "C:\myconfig.sql"` -> `& "C:\Program Files\myfile.exe" -i "C:\myconfig.sql"`

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell will strip outer quotes, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714165/powershell-stripping-double-quotes-from-command-line-arguments).

This is the same as why [`find.exe` doesn't work as expected in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/1208964/why-can-find-not-be-used-in-powershell).

You need to embed the double quotes inside single quotes, or escape the double quote by using `` `backticks` `` or by doubling the double quote:

- `cmd /c '"C:\Program Files\myfile.exe"' -i '"C:\myconfig.sql"'`
- `` cmd /c "`"C:\Program Files\myfile.exe`"" -i "`"C:\myconfig.sql`"" ``
- `` cmd /c "`"C:\Program Files\myfile.exe`"" -i `"C:\myconfig.sql`" ``
- `cmd /c """C:\Program Files\myfile.exe""" -i C:\myconfig.sql`
- ...

You can also use [PowerShell 3.0's verbatim arguments symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923315/using-in-powershell):

```
cmd /c --% "C:\Program Files\myfile.exe" -i "C:\myconfig.sql"
```

More about quoting rules in PowerShell is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core).

---

However unless you need an [internal command](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) of cmd like `dir`, `for`... you should avoid calling via cmd. Just call the program directly from PowerShell:

```
try
{
    "C:\Program Files\myfile.exe" -i "C:\myconfig.sql"
}
```

Comment: Testing this now!

Comment: Strange, I tried the first suggestion of yours, `cmd /c '"C:\Program Files\myfile.exe"' -i '"C:\myconfig.sql"'` and got the same error...

Comment: Just tried it with triple quotes and got the same error as well