# Pass a regex pattern to Perl Packer from Powershell

Tags: regex, windows, perl, powershell, par

How do I correctly write this in a Windows Powershell? Coming from macOS, I have some problems in understanding what it is wrong with this:

```
pp -u -g -o Executable -f Bleach="^(AAA_|BBB_|MainScript)" MainScript.pl
```

The regular expression to be passed to the option -f (filter) is not accepted and fires all sort of errors (command not recognized, and so on, no matter as I try to change it). On a Unix system it works just fine.

Comment: Iinsert `--%` to keep powershell from parsing your parameters. `pp --% -u -g -o Executable -f Bleach="^(AAA_|BBB_|MainScript)" MainScript.pl` See [using --% in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923315/using-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

[Escape character for Powershell](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html) is `.

Something like this could work:
`` pp -u -g -o Executable -f Bleach=`"`(AAA_`|BBB_`|MainScript`)`" MainScript.pl` ``