# How to retrieve the login command to use to authenticate your Docker client to your registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to push a docker image to aws by using Invoke-Expression -Command (Get-ECRLoginCommand -Region us-east-2).Command

but i Just want to know the correct format of this command to push the image

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it seems you want to push or pull the image from ECR. Here are the steps

1. configure first `aws configure` using `aws-cli` or assign role if you are on the remote server
2. then open the aws console of ECR if you are in us-west-2 or change the region [repositories region us-west-2](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecr/repositories?region=us-west-2#)
3. click on your repository and the select view push command
   [image]

Here is the command for window

```
Invoke-Expression -Command (Get-ECRLoginCommand -Region us-west-2).Command
```

The command for Linux/Mac

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
```

**update:**

This command retrieves and displays an authentication token using the GetAuthorizationToken API that you can use to authenticate to an Amazon ECR registry.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION
```

[get-login-password](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html)

Comment: yes i'm using windows command for pushing an image but it says that the Invoke-Expression command is not found

Comment: so its related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095493/invoke-expression-command-not-finding-file-even-though-it-exists

Comment: Since `get-login` is deprecated and replaced with `get-login-password`, is there another way to retrieve a Docker login command to the default registry?

Comment: yes `aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION`