# Powershell: Unquoting arguments when invoking an external command

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

Consider the following `cmd.exe` batch script:

```
testpar.cmd
@echo [%1] [%2]
```

If we call it it in Powershell, these results are rather obvious:

```
PS> .\testpar.cmd arg1 arg2
[arg1] [arg2]          
PS> .\testpar.cmd "arg1 arg2" 
["arg1 arg2"] []
```

But, when passing a variable:

```
PS> $alist= "arg1 arg2"      
PS> .\testpar.cmd $alist     
["arg1 arg2"] []
```

It seems that `$alist` is passed with quotes. 
One solution:

```
PS> $alist= "`"arg1`" `"arg2`""  
PS> .\testpar.cmd $alist                                   
["arg1"] ["arg2"]
```

which identifies arguments, but without stripping quotes.
Another possibility:

```
PS> Invoke-Expression  (".\testpar.cmd " + $alist)         
[arg1] [arg2]
```

This works, but is very convoluted.  Any better way?
In particular is there a way to *unquote*  a string variable?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just run the shell script as needed: `testpar.cmd arg1 "arg 2"`. PowerShell will automatically quote if needed. Why the question about unquoting a string variable?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: because there is something similar in the old cmd shell:  ` %~` . See `for /?` for more.

Comment: You could do it (remove quotes from the ends of a string), but what is the purpose of doing so? PowerShell does a pretty good job of quoting automatically where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient way to  me to pass `$alist` is:

```
PS> .\testpar.cmd $alist.Split()
[arg1] [arg2]
```

In this way I don't need to change the way I build `$alist`.
Besides `Split()` works well also for quoted long arguments:

```
PS> $alist= @"
>> "long arg1" "long arg2" 
>> "@
```

This is:

```
PS> echo $alist           
"long arg1" "long arg2"
```

and gives:

```
PS> .\testpar.cmd $alist.Split()     
["long arg1"] ["long arg2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/59c11446-e7ee-4e06-b472-2f5440e8ae91/powershell-commandline-passing-values-to-parameters-that-are-array-or-string-datatype?forum=winserverpowershell)

What you can do is use a comma: `$alist = "a,b"`

The comma will be seen as a paramater seperator:

```
PS D:\temp> $arglist = "a,b"
PS D:\temp> .\testpar.cmd $arglist
[a] [b]
```

You can also use an array to pass the arguments:

```
PS D:\temp> $arglist = @("a", "c")
PS D:\temp> .\testpar.cmd $arglist
[a] [c]
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would recommend using an array to build up a list of arguments, instead of mashing them all together into a single string:

```powershell
$alist = @('long arg1', 'long arg2')
.\testpar.cmd $alist
```

If you need to pass more complicated arguments, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468690/2495) useful.